# update listview on save

Tags: android, listview, sugarorm

I have a code where I add all TODOs to the adapter, like this

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);

     adapter = new TODOAdapter(this, TODO.listAll(TODO.class));
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

When add I new TODO, I do this

```
private void createTodo(String s) {
    TODOWorker.createTodo(s);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your TODO was saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but my listview is not beign updated...what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess after looking at your code is before calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your adapter you need to set the new list on the adapter. So when a new TODO is created add it to the list and update the list that the adapter is working with. Then call the `notifyDatasetChanged()`

So let's say your adapter has a `List<TODO> mDataList` then you need to have a function like this

```
public void setData(List<TODO> updatedList) {
    mDataList = new ArrayList<>(updatedList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and change your `createToDo()` to this

```
private void createToDo(String s) {
    TODOWorker.createTodo(s);
    adapter.setData(TODO.listAll(TODO.class));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your TODO was saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope this helps. I am assuming of course that your TODOWorker is not updating the list that the adapter is working with.

Answer (score 0):

When you create Adapter, it is backed by List, which you create by TODO.listAll(TODO.class)

You have to make sure that new item is inserted into this List before adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() called.

Comment: I'm sure the Item is inserted...but it the list backend comes from an ORM...I think this may be the problem...or am I talking cheap?